# How to implement OnTouchListener in an Activity using customized ImageView?

Tags: android

I have a customized `ImageView` and one of my Activities( say `Activity` A) uses that customized `ImageView`.
I like to implement `onTouchListener` for that customized view in `Activity` A.
I just implement `onTouchListener` as implementing for normal `ImageView`. But it doesn't work.

```
   DrawView m_view = null;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   m_view = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.textextraction_manipulation);  
   m_view .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Why it doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: did you try `return true`. try displaying a toast

Comment: yeah I do returning true. Still not called.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement something like this,

```
 m_view .setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch(event.getAction & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
           {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : //Do your stuff here
                                            break;

              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  //To do
                                         break;

            }
            return true;;
        }
    });
```